# Is there a way to use spring message brokers without Stompendpoints?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

We have a use case to create websocket server. Mobile clients will connect to this  websocket server. However mobile clients doesn't support stomp. 
We would like to create a Java websocket server. spring does support websockets but it's heavily coupled with STOMP. we like to use Spring message broker concept here but because of Stomp, we are struck now. Is there anyway to overcome this and enable Spring websocket without STOMP but with Spring message broker concept?